# Combing 4 outcomes in If Statement. Not Nested if

Tags: microsoft-excel

This is what I want to do:

- If A=1, "A is one" , "A is not 1"
- If B=2, "B is one" , "B is not 1"

How do I combine both of these if statements?

Comment: They are separate statements so how do you expect to combine them? The [general form](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2) is `IF(Statement; True; False)` you can put other functions into each of them.

Comment: Do you mean concatenating the results? `=IF(A1=1,"A is one","A in not one") & ", " & IF(B1=1,"B is one","B in not one")`?

Comment: You could use pseudo-code to show what you mean, then you broaden the audience of people that can try to answer.  Good pseudocode would include the terms then and, if need be, then else.

Comment: And it's not clear what you mean by 'combine'..  You could have them as separate statements.  Or you could ini a programming language connect them with If and Else, nesting them but without mad indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can `CONCATENATE` multiple `IF` statements together.

> =CONCATENATE(IF(A=1, "A is one, "A is not one), ", ", IF(B=1, "B is one, "B is not one))

You can concatenate together as many statements as you like.